# HTML CSS Centering Whole Site

Tags: html, css

I am new at css, html and I am designing a web site for my uncle's restaurant. I designed my first prototype in Adobe XD. Then I found a website called Avocode. I used css codes from there.

```
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 872px;
  left: 57px;
  width: 284px;
  height: 193px;
  z-index: +1;
}
```

Then I used  code at the html document.

```
<div class="logo"><img src="logo.png" alt=""></div>
```

It worked really well but I couldn't center the site. What should I do?

Comment: You should learn HTML and CSS. Tools which generate it are usually awful. (That code does not look like a sensible use of absolute positioning).

Comment: Hello Samet, welcome to SO. I kinda feel that, while the problem you have can be answered here, the right way to go forward is probably to do a few HTML+CSS tutorials as you will need to understand what happens when ammending to the solutions here. In fact, if you plan to create a whole website from scratch, you should probably spend a lot of time simply doodeling and trying to understand HTML+CSS+JS before writing a single line for that project.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and ideas. I'm very grateful. I will do some practice and modify all the codes. I will build more responsive website. :)

Answer (score 0):

A common, accepted, way to center an entire website is to use the `margin: auto;` approach.

```css
.content {
    width: 75%; /* Could be anything, but 75% works here. */
    margin: auto; /* This is what center the content div itself. */
    border: 1px solid red;
 }
 
 p {
     text-align: center; /* This will center the text inside the paragraph tag */
     border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
         <p>Here is some content!</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The goal is to wrap all your content into a single div and then center that div. This will allow you to still manipulate the styling of your objects inside that div, but overall the whole document will be centered.

Comment: note that the important part is `margin: auto;` and really only the left and right part of that (meaning that `margin: 0 auto` works the same, as does `margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto`, which would leave the other margins as they are)

Answer (score -1):

for me I really like to use CSS Grid for my projects.

If you'd want to use CSS grid you can just center something like this:

```
#element{
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center; /* horizontal centering */
    align-content: center; /* vertical centering */
}
```

In an example it would look like this.

```css
.logo {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily center an element

**CSS Flexbox**

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orangered;

  /* actually you need just these 3 properties specified below, the rest are for demo purposes */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container > p {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
<div class="container">
  <p>This is a paragraph, that will be centered</p>
</div>
```

**CSS Grids**

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  
  /* These 3 properties will suffice */
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.container > p {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>This is a paragraph, that will be centered</p>
</div>
```

**Absolute Positioning**

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: turquoise;
      
  /* Only display property will suffice */
  position: relative;
}

.container > p {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 1rem;
  
  /* These 4 properties are needed */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>This is a paragraph, that will be centered</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one I think its use full for you like your expectation.

```css
.logo img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  left: 45%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: +1;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/SQ7YhFZ/tire.png" alt=""></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Common HTML CSS Centering element**

```
<html>
<head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="logo"><img src="logo.png" alt="" /></div>
  </body>
</html>



 **css**
```

**Solution-1:**

```
.logo{
 position:absolute;
 display:inline-block;
 width: 284px;
 height: 193px;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 -webkit-transform:traslate(-50%,-50%);
 -ms-transform:traslate(-50%,-50%);
 transform:traslate(-50%,-50%);}

 .logo img{
 position:relative;
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 max-width:100%;
 max-height:100%;
 margin:auto auto;
 }

**Note:** It will center the div element depending on it's window screen size, when 
ever screen size is been resized the div element will be centered horizontally as 
well as to vertically.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by giving your `div` an `absolute` positioning and then moving the `div` 50% to the right and down. Then you just transform the `div` to 50% of the `div's` height and width and this will force it to the center of the page.

html:

```
<div class="logo">
 <img src="logo.png" alt="">
</div>
```

css:

```
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Explanation added.